# Development on iPhone with FPC

Tags: iphone, fpc

Tell me please where can I get iPhoneAll.pas file? Also could you tell me where can I find something about how can I use FPC to develop on iPhone, to use iPhone API? I've found several sites but it's not enough. For exapmle:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.setStatusBarHidden(true);

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES
```

First example is a Pascal realization of second example. I can't find any information how to change second example to Pascal realization, I just try to guess where and what I can change in my code to run it on iPhone))) but it takes much time

Answer (score 2):

You could always try typing iPhoneAll.pas into Google.

Check out this link:
http://www.bilsen.com/agkpas/documentation/5__Getting_Started_for_iOS.html